# how to change header title in react native functional component?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

i am using react-navigation v4 and i want to change the title and the approach i am using is slow while rendering(title that is set in the stack navigator is rendered first and then new one is rendered),is there better way i can render only the new one

```
export default NewsList = ({ results, navigation}) => {
    return <View >
        <FlatList
            data={results}
            keyExtractor={result => result.id}
            renderItem={({ item }) => {
                return (
                    <TouchableOpacity 
                        onPress={() => navigation.navigate( 'news',title: item.title)}>
                        <NewsCard result={item} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>)
            }}
        />
    </View>
};
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
export default NewsScreen = ({ navigation}) => {
    NewsScreen.navigationOptions = {
       title: navigation.getParam("title");,
       };
 }
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
const NewsStack = createStackNavigator({
NewsList :NewsList,
News :NewsScreen 

},{
    initialRouteName:'NewsList',
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
        
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#4BB5C3',
        },
      },
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'NewsList',
      },
});

export default createAppContainer(NewsStack);
```

Comment: Ciao, can you show me your TabNavigator? Thanks.

Comment: hi, I've added the stack navigator

Comment: Do you mean your title is dynamic when you click the flatlist item to navigate to a new screen?

Comment: yes i want to change the header title while i navigate from news list screen to news screen

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, try to set title before navigate into `NewsList` like this:

```
export default NewsList = ({ results, navigation}) => {
return <View >
    <FlatList
        data={results}
        keyExtractor={result => result.id}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
            return (
                <TouchableOpacity 
                    onPress={() => {
                        navigation.setParams({ otherParam: item.title });
                        navigation.navigate('news');
                     }
                  }>
                    <NewsCard result={item} />
                </TouchableOpacity>)
        }}
    />
</View>
};
```

And I think you could remove `navigationOptions` in `NewsScreen`.

Comment: I want to change the title from the component not stack navigator, the data to set title is only on the component

Comment: OK, give me more clues: "data to set title is only on the component" what do you mean? For logical reasons these data are only in component? data comes from a fetch? Title depends on what user selected ? Update your code with an example that allows me to undestand better.

Comment: yes data is fetched and is stored in 'results' variable and data has item called title which is passed to NewsScreen from where i have to set the header title

Comment: Ok I update my answer wit ha possible solution. Tell me if cuold be ok.

Comment: no man, its still not working, and i have tried everything in this snack https://snack.expo.io/?platform=android&name=updating%20navigationOptions&dependencies=%40react-native-community%2Fmasked-view%40%5E0.1.7%2Creact-navigation%40%5E4.4.0%2Creact-navigation-tabs%40%5E2.9.0%2Creact-navigation-stack%40%5E2.8.2%2Creact-navigation-drawer%40%5E2.5.0%2Creact-native-reanimated%40%5E1.7.0%2Creact-native-safe-area-context%40%5E0.7.3%2Creact-native-screens%40%5E2.4.0&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F4.x%2Fupdating-options-with-setparams.js